# How to pass a table of records as a parameter to an Oracle Stored procedure

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have an oracle stored procedure that accepts a table of records as its input parameter:

```
TYPE JREC is record
(
CUSTOMERID COMPANYS.COMPANYID%TYPE ,
JOBID JOBS.JOBID%TYPE,    
-----   
);

TYPE TJOBLIST IS TABLE OF JREC  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;    

PROCEDURE UPDATEJOBS(JRECS IN TJOBLIST )
IS
 BEGIN
     FOR i IN JRECS .FIRST .. JRECS .LAST LOOP
-----PROCEDURE BODY---
```

Please let me know how can I call this procedure from Delphi. I am using RAD Studio 2007

Answer (score 0):

You can call as this example:

```
DECLARE
  L_TABLE TJOBLIST ;
  NCOUNT PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

  L_TABLE := TJOBLIST(); --Create table
  L_TABLE.extend; --Add an element
  NCOUNT := L_TABLE.COUNT();
  L_TABLE(NCOUNT).CUSTOMERID := 1;
  L_TABLE(NCOUNT).JOBID := 10;
  L_TABLE.extend; --Add another element
  NCOUNT := L_TABLE.COUNT();
  L_TABLE(NCOUNT).CUSTOMERID := 2;
  L_TABLE(NCOUNT).JOBID := 20;
  L_TABLE.extend; --Add another element
  NCOUNT := L_TABLE.COUNT();
  L_TABLE(NCOUNT).CUSTOMERID := 3;
  L_TABLE(NCOUNT).JOBID  := 30;
  --.. and so on

  --Call the procedure and pass the table as a parameter
  UPDATEJOBS(L_TABLE);
END;
```